# Inequality of a weighted mean of $x^{k}$ and $y^{k}$

Tags: inequality

Is there an argument for the following inequality using only the basic algebraic properties of inequalities and using the Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality, Young's Inequality, the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality, and Bernouli's Inequality?

**Theorem**

$s$ and $t$ are conjugate (positive) real numbers~---~they total to 1~--~and $x$ and $y$ are any real numbers.
\begin{equation*}
sx^{k} + ty^{k} \geq \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} (sx)^{i}(ty)^{k-i}
\end{equation*}
for any nonnegative integer $k$.

**Demonstration in the case $k=2$**

According to the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality, for any positive real numbers $x$ and $y$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{2} \geq xy .
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
st(x^{2} + y^{2}) \geq 2stxy ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
t(sx^{2}) + s(ty^{2}) \geq 2stxy ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
(1 - s)sx^{2} + (1 - t)ty^{2} \geq 2stxy ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
sx^{2} + ty^{2} \geq s^{2}x^{2} + 2stxy + t^{2}y^{2} .
\end{equation*}
(If either $x$ or $y$ is a negative real number, $\vert xy \vert \geq xy$.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial formula, your inequality becomes
$$
 (sx + ty)^k \le s x^k + t y^k \, .
$$
With $f(x) = x^k$ and using $s+t =1$ this becomes
$$
 f(sx + (1-s)y) \le s f(x) + (1-s)f(y) \quad \text{ for } 0 \le s \le 1
$$
which is exactly the condition for $f$ to be *convex*.

If $k$ is even then $f(x) = x^k$ is convex on $\Bbb R$,
so that the inequality is true for any $x, y \in \Bbb R$.

If $k$ is odd then $f(x) = x^k$ is convex on $[0, \infty)$,
so that the inequality is true for any $x, y \ge 0$.

But the inequality is false for $x, y < 0$ and odd $k$ because then  $z \to z^k$ 
is concave on the negative real numbers so that the inverse 
inequality holds.

Comment: Yes, I see that you recognized the identity $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} (sx)^{i} (ty)^{k-i} = (sx + ty)^{k}$, and you cite the convexity of the power function $x^{k}$ on the interval $[0, \, \infty)$.

Comment: @user74973: Are you asking *why* $x^k$ is convex? The second derivative is $\ge 0$.

Comment: I was just commenting on your argument.

Comment: @user74973: If anything is missing or unclear in my argument then please let me know.